# Code editor does not have a "project/folder" button

Tags: code, editor

When I see the screenshots on [Github](https://github.com/elementary/code/blob/3.2.0/README.md) then I have to conclude that my code editor looks a bit different:

[image: code editor]

Between the "Open file" button and the "Save file"-button in the left top corner of the image should appear the "Project/folder"-button. I can toggle the sidebar, but that is not useful without a project.

This code-editor came with elementary OS and I did not install it myself. Do I have to uninstall and install it again to get this functionality? Or do I need to install a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the `io.elementary.code` works as expected. You just need to open a folder inside it which is called a `workspace/project`

Try the following command for **elementary OS 5.1 Hera**

`io.elementary.code ~`[image]

**So to answer your question** Look at the bottom left corner of the screenshot I attached. That's the open `Project button`

#### Note

Also, make sure the sidebar is turned on

Comment: Thank you @AbdElraouf Sabri. This works for me. I still don't see the button in the top left corner, though. But the button in the bottom left corner does the same.

Comment: That may be a theming issue, cuz the button does exist but in the bottom left corner